# Python dictionary comes with an extra curly bracket, as a JSON key, through HttpResponse

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I am sending a particular JSON via a GET request to a Django server. The JSON is as follows.

```
data = {
            test1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            test2: {
                test21: ['a', 'b'],
                test22: 'data22'
            }
        };
```

**Edit 2:** Code for sending the data:

```
string = JSON.stringify(data)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/calc/?' + string
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {console.log(response)});
```

**End of Edit 2**

After I `stringify` this and send it, I am running the following code on the request data.

```
def calc (request):
    data = request.GET
    z = dict(data.iterlists())
    res = json.dumps(z)
    return HttpResponse(res)
```

The http response comes out as follows:

`Object {{"test1":[1,2,3,4],"test2":{"test21":["a","b"],"test22":"data22"}}: Array[1]}`

The Array[1] element is basically an empty array, so that's useless.
When I change the third line in the code to

`z = dict(data.iteritems())`

I get the following response

`Object {{"test1":[1,2,3,4],"test2":{"test21":["a","b"],"test22":"data22"}}: ""}`

Basically the JSON I require comes out as a key to another JSON. I know I can use the `Object.keys()` method to extract out the required JSON, but I would like the response to be correct.

How do I fix this in python?

**Edit 1:** I think the error is arising when I am converting my data into a `dict` item in line 3. I think this because operations on `z`, which is supposed to be a `dict` are throwing error. For instance `y = z['test1']` throws an error.

Comment: How did you `stringify and send it` exactly?

Comment: I used `JSON.strigify()` on `data` and attached it to the URL. The server is picking it up fine, because when I send back `data` as response instead of converting it to a dictionary object, it sends out the JSON perfectly.

Comment: Then how do you attach it to the URL exactly?. I think we kinda need the whole picture and details.

Comment: I added the code I used to send the GET request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you sent your data is sort of wrong.

When you are using GET, the url is like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

What you did above actually makes the json string the **key** instead of **value**. Hence the wrong request format.

I think what you need to do is like:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/calc/?payload=' + string
```

This will make `payload` the key and your actual string the value. And to retrieve it:

```
data = request.GET
json_string = data['payload']
# load the string
```

Comment: Alright. So this worked. When I did `data['payload']`, it returns a unicode format. I used `ast.literal_eval(json_string)` to convert it into a operable dictionary so I can run my calculations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1508) article out.

Specifically,

```
return HttpResponse(res, content_type = "application/json")
```

You're missing the `content_type` qualifier.

Furthermore, you really should be using `serializers.serialize` like

```
def calc(request):
  data = request.GET
  return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", data), 
    content_type = 'application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I need to convert the request data (that comes as a `QueryDict` into a `Dict` to operate on it a little, and then send it back as response. So doing this will not be useful.

Comment: Then I think this is a direct result of your client side data conversion.  Can you get the data payload via Firebug/Chrome Inspector and see if it passes JSON linting?  In addition, you can take advantage of the built in Django deserialization functionality https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data